# Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:15'

Tags: android, google-api

I am trying to install some android developer plugins. After the installation is done, i see this warning 3 times in the console. Why does this error occur and how can i get rid of it ?
If I ignore this error, how will it affect me later ?

[cloudnotes-preview-android-sample] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:15'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure you have that target downloaded.
You can do this through Eclipse.

Just click on the SDK-Manager tool. It's the little Android guy with the down arrow.
Then make sure you have the correct target package installed.

Comment: Which is the correct target package ? I want to use version 2.0 because it is used by my book.

Comment: If you right click on your project in Eclipse an then go ->Properties->Android It'll give you a listing of all the target packages you have installed (2.0 should be included in that list). If there isn't anything there, then you have to make sure to download it using the steps I gave you in the answer. Please make sure to upvote and accept, if my answers helped you :) It makes me happy and leads to continued help, lol

Comment: And by project, I mean the top level folder