# Unable to resolve project target during ant release

Tags: android, ant

I genereate an ant script from eclipse and try to check if it will work before to pass it to the teamcity server. Unfortunatly ant release is failed with message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:517: Unable to resolve project target 'android-15'
```

In prohect properties I use target=android-15, this SDK was inatlled in my computer, ant uses java 1.6. Where is the cause of this issue? Could you help me to find it?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11458846/760489

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I have downloaded this sdk befor start ant release

Answer (score 2):

List target:

```
android list target
```

Update target for project:

```
android update project --target target_id -p .
```